# Best way to avoid multiple parallel if else loop in java 8

Tags: java, dictionary, if-statement, java-8

What is the best way to avoid multiple parallel if-else loop. I tried with `switch` statement as well, but again that doesn't look readable. I have hundreds of such statements:

```
public static Map getKqvSecureNodeResponse(Sample secureNodeData, Map<String, Object> map) {
    if(map.containsKey(Constants.NAME_KQV)) {
        map.put(Constants.NAME_KQV, secureNodeData.getNodename());
    }
    if(map.containsKey(Constants.SPOV)) {
        map.put(Constants.SPOV, secureNodeData.getOverride());
    }
    if(map.containsKey(Constants.SPEP)) {
        map.put(Constants.SPEP, secureNodeData.getEnabledProtocol());
    }
    if(map.containsKey(Constants.SPTO)) {
        map.put(Constants.SPTO, secureNodeData.getAuthTimeout());
    }
    if(map.containsKey(Constants.TLCN)) {
        map.put(Constants.TLCN, secureNodeData.getCommonName());
    }
    if(map.containsKey(Constants.SEDT)) {
        map.put(Constants.SEDT, secureNodeData.getEncryptData());
    }
    if(map.containsKey(Constants.TLCF)) {
        map.put(Constants.TLCF, secureNodeData.getKeyCertLabel());
    }
    if(map.containsKey(Constants.TLCL)) {
        map.put(Constants.TLCL, secureNodeData.getCipherSuites());
    }
    return map;
}
```

Please note that I have to invoke different getter of secureNodeData for every check.

Comment: But I have to invoke diffrent getter depending on the if clause. `secureNodeData.getNodename()` would be called for `map.containsKey(Constants.NAME_KQV)` only.

Comment: I feel, you need to rethink about your application design

Comment: `switch` might help the branches look cleaner, yet must revisit your design probably as pointed by @Ravi. Also, the part `Map<String, Object>` is way to generic IMO.

Comment: I would use `computeIfAbsent` and `switch` inside it.

Comment: Could you provide the source code of the `Sample` class? The solution might be there if revisited a little.

Comment: @nullpointer I vote to reopen this question because the specific code here can be rewritten using method references (Java 8), unlike the other questions that are too general for such answer.

Comment: @Antoniossss OP validates the condition `map.containsKey`, so it should be `computeIfPresent` (they'd rather override the value)

Answer (score 3):

For each `Constants` value (e.g. `Constants.NAME_KQV`), you can provide a `Function<Sample, Object>` (e.g. `sample -> sample.getNodename()`).

If you organised it in a structure like `Map` or `enum` (here, I used a enum), you could end up with a simple loop:

```
public static Map<String, Object> getKqvSecureNodeResponse(Sample secureNodeData, Map<String, Object> map) {
    for (Constant constant : Constant.values()) {
        final String name = constant.getName();
        if (map.containsKey(name)) {
            map.put(name, constant.getFunction().apply(secureNodeData));
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

The enum was defined as:

```
enum Constant {
    NAME_KQV(Constants.NAME_KQV, Sample::getNodename);
    // other definitions

    final String name;
    final Function<Sample, Object> function;

    Constant(String name, Function<Sample, Object> function) {
        this.name = name;
        this.function = function;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Function<Sample, Object> getFunction() {
        return function;
    }
}
```

It seems like this method does a lot. (1) It's unclear why it overrides existing values. (2) The method name is obscure. (3) You are using a raw `Map`, replace it with `Map<String, Object>` at least, and figure out how to substitute the `Object` part. (4)

I feel rethinking the design would help much more than the above approach and these small corrections.

Comment: Mind the different treatment of `null` values…

Comment: `null` values will be filtered out by `computeIfPresent`, won't they?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I will try this code and accept it as answer soon. Thanks much for this answer. I can't change the code of Sample class as we're using some dependent jar and I can't modify it.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko if there are keys mapping to `null`, `computeIfPresent` will treat them as absent, whereas `containsKey` will report the keys as present, so this solution will have a different behavior than the original code, if the incoming map has `null` values. And since this method is supposed to replace the values, this might not be too far-fetched.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to take advantage of method references:

```
public static Map getKqvSecureNodeResponse(Sample node, Map<String, Object> map) {
    applyParam(Constants.NAME_KQV, map, node::getNodename);
    applyParam(Constants.SPOV, map, node::getOverride);
    // ...
}

public static void applyParam(String key, Map<String, Object> data, Supplier<Object> getter) {
    if (data.containsKey(key)) {
        data.put(key, getter.get());
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use `Function` references that are instance independent:

```
private static final Map<String, Function<Sample, Object>> MAPPING;
static {
    MAPPING = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    MAPPING.put(Constants.NAME_KQV, Sample::getNodename);
    MAPPING.put(Constants.SPOV, Sample::getOverride);
}

public static Map getKqvSecureNodeResponse(Sample node, Map<String, Object> map) {
    for (String key : MAPPING.keySet()) {
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.put(key, MAPPING.get(key).apply(node));
        }
    }
}
```

---

There are many ways how you can approach your specific use case, but method references in general makes developer's life much much easier.